# C# - Does FirstOrDefault() return null in this case?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I hope this question respects the StackOverflow guidelines.
I have a table (`ResultsTable`) in my DB (SQL Server management studio) in which the columns are:

```
ID (PK, FK, int, not null)
RiskRate (PK, int, not null)
FileName (PK, nvarchar(100), not null)
```

In C# I've used `EF`. In my code, there is a method `SelectFileNames(string fileName)`:

```
    var resultSearch = (from result in DB.ContextManagement.ResultTable
                        where result.FinaName.compareTo(fileName) == 0
                        select result).FirstOrDefault();
    if (resultSearch == null)
         ...
    else
         ...
```

The `FirstOrDefault()` method has this description:

```
 Returns the first element of the sequence that satisfies a condition
 or a default value (TSource) if no such element is found.
```

So, how can I force `FirstOrDefault()` to return `null` if there isn't an element with that filename? NB: in my table `ResultTable`, the columns have the `not null` constraint.

Thanks.

Comment: If `result` is a reference type, it returns `null`.

Comment: resultSearch is ResultTable type. result is ResultTable type too.

Comment: You have reference types (`class`) and value types (`struct`) in C#. There is no such thing as a ResultTable type. That might be the _name_ of a type?

Comment: So yes, that's a reference type. :P The nullability of the columns is not relevant here. In the rare case where you are selecting non-nullable value types but you'd still like a `null` result, you can insert a `Cast<int?>()` or suchlike before the `.FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: ReusltTable is in the entities of my context. For example:
var context = new MyDBContext and MyDBContext is a partial class of DbContext.

ResultTable is in context. So I can do that: context.ResultTable

Comment: Have you actually checked if it returns `null`? It should do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in your query

```
(from result in DB.ContextManagement.ResultTable
                        where result.FinaName.compareTo(fileName) == 0
                        select result)
```

no entity respect your condition then the `FirstOrDefault` will return `null`.

It is specified in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=net-6.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_FirstOrDefault__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__)

"Remarks
The default value for reference and nullable types is null."

Since the type of `result` is a reference type it will return `null`.

Comment: Thank you. I've read the doc, I was confused about TSource source empty vs source null

Answer (score 0):

try like this .

[image]

```
            List<Users> userlist = new ();

            userlist.Add(new Users() {username = "testuser",password = "testpass"});
            userlist.Add(new Users() { username = "testuser2", password = "" });


            var result = userlist.FirstOrDefault(s => s.username == "testuser2")?.password;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following syntaxe

```
var resultSearch = DB.ContextManagement.ResultTable.Where(x => x.FileName == fileName).ToList() ;
if (resultSearch.Count > 0)
     ...
else //Get the first element of list
```

Comment: `resultSearch` will never be `null` in this case. If there are zero results, you will have an empty list.

Comment: I forgot to modify the if statment, the goal is to check if resultSearch is null, équivalent .Count>0 here